# How to disguise a ghost with the Masquerade in full effect?

Tags: mythical-creatures, modern-age, medical, ghosts

Okay, so I have a world just like ours, except all the myths are real. Maybe.
The Masquerade is in full effect - there is no such thing as monsters and you'd be crazy to say otherwise. This is vastly helped by the fact that most monsters either look like humans or hide fairly effectively. There is also a small government branch that helps with ID and all that if you're a law-abiding monster (and sends hunters if not).

Of course, no disguise is 100% foolproof, so you occasionally need excuses. A Vampire might claim having migraines to explain their need to stay out of the sun, or anemia for their pale skin and need for regular blood donations.

Werewolves might actually go with a fake disease like Lycanthropy and just claim the doctor who discovered it thought it was funny because the symptoms match so well *(eyeroll)*. Hormone imbalance linked to moon phases and all that, gets really painful with cramps and seizures... children sometimes suffer hallucinations, too. Explains everything.

I'm kinda stuck on what to do with my ghosts, though. Depending on their strength, they are either invisible unless you know how to look, or they look like regular people. There is some in between, but for the sake of the question, let's assume the ghost is powerful enough to look fully human. Visible, tangible, smells mostly human (some incense, too), even his shadow and reflection align, he's breathing and has a pulse.
Assuming he fakes all of that well enough, the only thing that betrays him is the light behind his pupils - so faint you can't see it unless it's really dark, but it flares badly on camera. Everyone has cameras nowadays.
Another problem is that the ghost can only leave his haunted house for a limited time. How long varies with how much energy he has - he might go on a lengthy vacation one time, or be stuck indoors for months at other times. His comfortable average is three to six hours a day, which is little time to get a job if you look young and healthy enough to work fulltime.

So, in short:

1.) How does the ghost prevent being exposed when he mustn't be caught on camera with his eyes open?

2.) What (medical?) condition could explain his inability to work full-time/ leave the house at times?

Comment: You want just an excuse for the ghost to not have a job, or you actually want the ghost to work? (What a ghost need a job for, I'd ask: he does not need to eat, to clothe, and can't really do nothing with the money. Paying for a Netflix subscription?) Because if it's the former, they can just claim a disability and tell everyone they live from welfare benefits. It explains also why they don't go often outdoors.

Comment: @Rekesoft I want to get the ghost a job, yes. Mainly for the benefit of being busy, outdoors, and able to connect to people while feeling useful. And, yes, help out with the electricity bill for videogames and all that. ;)

Answer (score 6):

> 1.) How does the ghost prevent being exposed when he mustn't be caught on camera with his eyes open?

[Partially mirrored contact lenses](https://www.colouredcontacts.com/gb/view-all/1029551-silver-mirror-coloured-prescription-contact-lenses-30-day.html?SubmitCurrency=yes&id_currency=4). These come in different strengths and he can mess around with a camera in selfie mode to find the strength that disguises his glowy pupils by reflecting light from elsewhere.

That site offers all kinds of variants that allow one to change their eye colour and other crazy stuff.  He may be able to get by with a simple semi-opaque lens as used by cosplayers when their eye colour doesn't match up with their character.

> 2.) What (medical?) condition could explain his inability to work fulltime/ leave the house at times?

Covid19 explains why I've been working at home for a year.

Even before covid19 there was jobs advertised as work remotely full time - some job sites even allow you to filter by that. Allowing staff to live away from an office saves everyone money.

If you want an actual medical condition, I'd suggest MS - I live with someone with MS, some good days she's full ability, some bad days she can't get out of bed, and some medium days she needs a wheelchair. It totally explains why sometimes he can party for days, and sometimes he disappears for months.

Comment: Do those contact lenses cover the pupil, though? I figured those might be an option, but the only fully covering ones I found where either completely white or all-black fetish lenses designed to blind the wearer.

I'll definitley read up MS, that might be a good fit.

Comment: I have multiple friends and family members with MS (Multiple Sclerosis) and can confirm, some days they're out and about and all is well, other days they can't get out of bed, let alone leave the house. It's the perfect excuse. "Sorry, my MS is flaring up and I need to stay home"

Answer (score 3):

> 1.) How does the ghost prevent being exposed when he mustn't be caught on camera with his eyes open?

Work from home office, use deep fake technology if you need to participate in videoconferences. It also just came to me that a lot of youtube channels I watch are infotainment channels hosted by animated characters (TheOdds1Out, Brew, Sam O'Nella Academy and CGP Grey come to mind).

> 2.) What (medical?) condition could explain his inability to work fulltime/ leave the house at times?

The ghost might just tell everyone he is an incel. People will be glad that he doesn't leave his house.

On a more serious note, there is a condition called [Hikikomori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori) - I could swear there was an English term for it, it was common among World of Warcraft players years ago.

> The Japanese Ministry of Health, Labour, and Welfare defines hikikomori as a condition in which the affected individuals refuse to leave their parents' house, do not work or go to school and isolate themselves away from society and family in a single room for a period exceeding six months.

Failing all that, the ghost might be just extremely obese. [There is a very american reality show that documents the life and times of people too heavy to leave their own beds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_600-lb_Life).

---

> Another problem is that the ghost can only leave his haunted house for a limited time. How long varies with how much energy he has - he might go on a lenghty vaccation one time, or be stuck indoors for months at other times. His comfortable average is three to six hours a day, which is litte time to get a job if you look young and healthy enough to work fulltime.

That's called being an introvert. Half the world was already like that even before the pandemic, and I'm not counting just millenials, Gen Z or whatever the current generation is.

Comment: thats not being an introvert, thats just plain being antisocial. those are two separate things

Comment: Hikikomori and full home office would be ideal, but would have the ghost stay home 24/7. I want him to be out and about and extroverted, but unable to keep that up for too long. Also, being an introvert is rarely accepted as an excuse if you say you want to work and go to social outings, but not full-time. Especially if you look happy and healthy.

Answer (score 2):

- Preventing the ghost's eye's from being recorded on camera.

The use of glasses due to perfectly plausible living conditions such as migraines/light sensitivity/partial blindness.

The glasses have a tint/sheen to them that blocks any camera's ability to record the eye feature you are worried about. As for face to face encounters, any living beings paying enough attention to notice the eye feature, can explain it away as a trick of light reflecting off the glasses.

- how to explain ghost not leaving the house

Same medical conditions mentioned above could explain most of it away (while partial blindness shouldn't be a reason to restrict oneselve to home, it can be used as an "excuse").

Your ghost also tells ppl that he works odd hours and doesn't keep a 9-5 "normal" office schedule. No one would bat an eyelid at that.

- Also note, that unless you are actually spying on your neighbour, do *you* know how much time they spend outside the house (precovid)?

Your ghost can certainly play off that with such idle chatter whilst taking out the rubbish or over the fence gossip about how he went to the shops earlier in the day or got stuck in that traffic jam that was conventiently broadcast on the radio that morning. How are your neighbour's or friend's who don't live in same street as you,  to know when you left/returned to the house. I mean, they would just assume wouldn't they.

Answer (score 0):

Your ghost could claim to have agoraphobia, a psychological condition which makes leaving the house extremely difficult, even traumatic to the sufferer.

As for avoiding being photographed with their eyes open, just avoid being photographed at all.  All modern cameras are electronic in nature and ghosts have influence over electricity as proven by the flickering of lights during hauntings.  Just short out all cameras and cellphones within the confines of the house.

From there, maintaining the masquerade requires only a warm-bodied assistant to visit the house on a regular basis, delivering empty groceries (eating is for the living) and take out the trash (last week's empty groceries).